# django finding file in custom static folder returns none

Tags: django

I am trying to find file in custom static folder and it returns `None`

I created a folder named `static_test` in the project folder and added `STATICFILES_DIRS` in settings.py

```py
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    ("test",os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_test'))
]
```

I also added static_url to `urlpatterns` in the main folder.

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

When I call on find a file (in the folder) it returns `None`

```py
from django.contrib.staticfiles import finders
...
value = 'file.png'
finders.find(value)
```

I checked `finders.searched_locations` and the folder is there
What am I missing here?

Comment: did you run `collectstatic`?

Comment: @karinaklinkevičiūtė `collectstatic` is for deployment, i'm running in local

Answer (score 1, accepted):

removed the **prefix** in STATICFILES_DIRS and everything worked